# Rspec: ||= operator repeatedly evaluates code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec for testing. I have this piece of code:

```
class Service
  def execute
    all_users.update_all(status: 'deactive')
  end

  def all_users
    @all_users ||= User.status_active
  end
end
```

Then I have the following two expectations:

```
expect(service.all_users.count).to eq 10
service.execute
expect(service.all_users.count).to eq 0
```

They both return `true`. It means that the first time I call `all_users`, it is evaluated once. And on the second call, `all_users` is evaluated again, this time because I have changed all user's state to `deactive` and the total active users is zero.

The `||=` operator evaluates the code for the variable only on the first time. Why is my code above evaluated again?

Comment: Is service.object_id same in all three cases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `User.all_users` is either a scope or a class method which does something like `where(status: 'active')`.

In such case, `User.all_users` returns not a collection of models, but a lazily evaluated SQL query. When you write `User.status_active`, you actually make a new SQL query and get actual data

Answer (score 4):

What Andry said is true; the value saved in `@all_users` is not just an array or list, it's an `ActiveRecord` relation. When you call `all_users.count`, it will make a db query to determine the result.